# Why does gnome-terminal display ���?

Tags: terminal, display, gnome-terminal, character-encoding

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with GNOME Terminal 2.30.2, but when I ssh into a RedHat server, my terminal does not display correctly.

For example, the help pages for R look like this:

```
 Objects of class ���"glm"��� are normally of class ���c("glm", "lm")���,
 that is inherit from class ���"lm"���, and well-designed methods for
 class ���"lm"��� will be applied to the weighted linear model at the
 final iteration of IWLS.  However, care is needed, as extractor
 functions for class ���"glm"��� such as ���residuals��� and ���weights��� do
 *not* just pick out the component of the fit with the same name.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I ��� Unicode!  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charset on the local system and the charset on the remote system don't match. You can verify this by executing `locale charmap` on each system. Set `$LANG` on the remote system appropriately to fix this.

Comment: you are right. my local system uses ANSI and the remote system uses UTF-8. But how do I set $LANG? Although I can't change the remote system, on my desktop `LANG='UTF-8'` did not change the charset

Comment: You have to start gnome-terminal with the correct charset; changing it after the fact isn't enough. `LANG=en_US.utf-8 gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 4):

As Wil suggested, the terminal is attempting to display multibyte Unicode characters but the font does not support the characters in question or there is no Unicode support at all.  As a result, placeholder characters are used in their place indicating that the characters cannot be properly displayed.

A possible solution is to select a different font with better Unicode support.  However, make sure that the font is monospaced - consistent character spacing is expected in a terminal emulator.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reference, I have no idea how to fix it and was going to write similar to this as a comment but had a phone call so just wrote that little joke!

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work - I have it set to the moospace font 'monaco' by default, but the error also occurs with 'monospace'. However, I did notice that the problem only occurs when I have ssh'd and am working on a server. I have changed my question to reflect this.

Comment: This may be caused by the terminal type being emulated.  Some terminals do not support Unicode and will cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal's profile and change the font to something with "Mono" in the name, like Monospace or Liberation Mono.